# How to pass 2 tf datasets to .fit as sequence and tags?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I’ve loaded two datasets with sentences and labels from txt file with TextLineDataset, vectorized them by .map. Now I need to pass this data to model.fit. And I’ve found, that I can’t pass datasets directly to model as x and y. I need to do .as_numpy_iterator() or convert to dataset in format like ((all_first_dataset_elements), (all_second_dataset_elements)), that is not easy task. So, in my opinion both options are a bit ugly. I am sure, that should be more easy and logical way to use built-in datasets. Can you give me idea how to do it as it has to be?